# 18.04 hangs on boot after system software update

Tags: boot, gnome, 18.04

I have two users on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.

Normally I work with user1. Today I switched to user2 and started software update. (As far as I remember a few things were installed and some unnecessary ones removed).

When I rebooted it stopped for a long time at the first dot of the splash screen. So I pressed Ctrl+Alt+Del. Then the system shut down.

Now system boots until the splash screen and then switches to text mode. Last message:

```
ubuntu 18.04 boot  "Started GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher Service ....rfkill Watch.   
Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down."
```

With Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2 I can log in. The first time a message appeared that Canonical live patch applied 0 or so.

The machine is normally running 7/24 and is very important to me! How should I proceed?

[image]

EDIT:

now comes:
ubuntu 18.04 boot  "started GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher Service ....d before the  ppp link was shut down"

Comment: Exactly which kernel? (It's important - one has a critical bug in process as of 03 July 2018)

Comment: How to find out?

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB and look in /boot.

Comment: I can login user ctrl + alt + f1 f2. uname -r says 4.15.0-24-generic.  I'm new to linux. Should I proceed as described here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051555/after-security-update-to-4-15-0-24-generic-26-ubuntu-screen-shows-log-content

Comment: I agree you have the "bad" kernel. Try to boot into the previous one.

Comment: neither left shift nor right shift works to get to grub menu. Can anyone recommend which steps I need to do?

Comment: It's a standard ubuntu 18.04 installation. How can I get into grub menu to select a previous kernel? shift didn't do anything

Comment: (For me it was hitting ESC multiple times) however when I boot with 0-23-generic I get the same error message, What should I do now?

Comment: Since it's a new install, one option is to reinstall with a -23 or older kernel.

Comment: It booted now. What did I do (see link above) 1. boot 23. 2.install lightdm. 3. reboot --> black screen. 4. reboot to 23. 5. sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm --> selected old  one. 6. rebooted. worked. Don't know if it works again if i reboot again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After "security update" to 4.15.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu screen shows log content not login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051555/after-security-update-to-4-15-0-24-generic-26-ubuntu-screen-shows-log-content)